# Paperclip & Passenger: How to increase upload file size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, passenger

I'm using paperclip to handle the upload stuff on ruby on rails project, when I deploy it to production server, I found I can't upload a **big** file (even only 3MB), I will get redirect to "this webpage is not available"(chrome) and I can upload a 1.5MB file. I'm no idea what causing that happen.
I can't reproduce it on localhost with production mode, we don't have any validation with paperclip, here is the attachment model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :attachment
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :attachment
end
```

We are using Apache & Passenger on server, and we don't have something like `LimitRequestBody` in our config. Not sure what else would be causing that.

#### Update:

Found the following error from the passenger log:

```
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data: Unknown error 18446744073709551514 (-102)
  Backtrace:
     in 'boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::BufferedUpload> Hooks::receiveRequestBody(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:1155)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:532)
```

Some related discussion: https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=288, they suggest to extend the timeout, but I don't think it's a good idea.

At last fix by using `thin` instead of `passenger`.

Comment: Are you using AWS (Amazon Web Services)?

Comment: @JohnC no, we store the files on our server, we have another project deploy in the same server and it can upload big file with paperclip, I have tried to track down their difference but no luck.

Comment: I had a really similar problem on AWS.  It turned out to be that there was a temporary directory missing in passenger.  All I can say is check the logs for passenger and it might give you some clues.

Comment: @JohnC I will look over it, thanks for your idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes webservers like `apache` or `nginx` limit the upload file size. Depending on whether you are using Passenger in standalone mode or as a server module, look for your webserver configuration and increase the limit there.